# How is ものがある used?

Tags: set-phrases

So I came across this sentence:

> あなたをむかえる**ものがある**。

My take on it is: `There is a thing that will meet you.` I know that's wrong. So how is ものがある used?

ADDED: Is there a difference between ことがある and　ものがある？

Comment: This is `あなたを迎える者がある`。`者` defines a person.

Comment: ことがある and ものがある each have a number of different usages, it's an important question but I think it'd need to be asked separately.

Comment: @cypher: Will do.

Comment: @oldergod: It means: `There's a person who/that will meet you.` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it from [this song](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-9022.html) by ALI Project?

If so, the Kanji is 者 "person", not 物 which means "thing", as Oldergod said in a comment:

> ...あなたを迎える者がある。
>   ...there is someone who will greet you.

Comment: I thought this was the mono like koto. Not mono = person. I wish I saw the kanji version. Thanks.

Comment: Why not いる then?