# Is there a difference between ことがある and　ものがある？

Tags: word-choice, set-phrases

This has been split from [this question.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/how-is-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-used).

So what are differences between two? Are there times where they can be interchangeable or can they only be used in certain situations?

I saw this about [ことがある.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/the-different-usages-of-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B)

Comment: Would you have a sentence that confuses you? Or when you think that you can switch both ?

Answer (score 2):

For ものがある:

- (plain form verb/i adjective/na adjective+な)+ものがある (Kanji 物がある, but I think it's usually written in Hiragana), can mean:

  > - とても〜だ
  > - なんとなく〜感じる
  > - 〜という感じがある
  > - 〜ように感じられる

  and is used in regards with things the speaker felt, for expressing feelings while describing the characteristics of something, or that a certain characteristic can be seen, for example:

  > 半年前にいなくなったねこが帰ってきた。わたしにとって特別うれしいものがある。
  >     "The cat which disappeared half a year ago has returned. To me it's special, and I feel very happy."
  >
  > この文章はまだまだ未熟だが、しかし随所にキラリと光るものがある。
  >     "This sentence has still got some way to go, but it twinkles at every turn."
  >
  > この絵には人を引きつけるものがある。
  >     "This painting feels like it pulls a person into it."

  You can also use 見られる, 認められる etc in place of ある here.

  (Sources: 日本語文型辞典, どんな時どう使う日本語文型辞典500, the Kanzen master JLPT 2 grammar book).
- It can also mean "there is a thing (generally a tangible thing)" (with the Kanji 物がある).
- ものがある can also mean "there is a person" (written with the Kanji 者がある)

For ことがある:

- It can mean "there are times when..." when expressed as plain form verb+ことがある and "there are times when it doesn't" when expressed as plain negative verb+ことがある
- It can express that something has been experienced when expressed as plain past+ことがある, and that something hasn't been experienced when expressed as plain past+ことがない.
- It can also mean "there is a thing (generally abstract)" as well. [(It is structurally ambiguous between an appositive clause and a relative clause)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3978/542)

The question you [linked to](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/the-different-usages-of-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B) describes these usages in more detail, so I think I might leave those for now.

There are probably many other different usages too, but the two are generally quite different to each other as far as I know. I think as a (possibly broad generalization) that ものがある tends to be about feelings and tangible things and ことがある tends to be about abstract things, experiences and occurrences etc.