# What's the meaning of こと in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

> 聞いたことない！

I'm still confused about the meaning of こと. But I think it means "this," "that," "about," and maybe "it."

So, this sentence could be translated as: "I've never heard of this/that/it!"

But I'm not very sure ...

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3979/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9432/9831

Answer (score 6):

The structure **Past verb + こと + ある/ない** means that you **Ever/Never** Performed a given "action".

Examples:

> 日本に行ったこと**ない**。Nihon ni itta koto nai. - I have **never** been to Japan.

Now a conversation about two people talking about Nattou (Japanese fermented beans)

> Person1 - 納豆を食べたこと**ある**？Nattou wo tabeta kot aru? - Have you ever eaten Nattou?
>
> Person 2 - はい、納豆を食べたこと**ある**よ！Hai, Nattou wo tabeta koto aru yo! - Yes, I have already eaten Nattou!

So, **聞いたことない** probably means "I have never heard about that."!

If you want to be a bit literal "The thing of having heard that does not exist"

Comment: Hello. In formal Japanese, is there a が between こと and ない or ある, or ありません and あります?

Comment: @BIG-95 that's debatable, I used to believe that yes, we should not omit any particles in formal speech, but i've seen people correct me when I wrote something like 行ったことがある to 行ったことある. I guess removing the が removes the focus from 行った and then the focus is the whole sentence. That maybe would be a good question for the site :)